# C# update combobox with Database values

Tags: c#, database, combobox

Hello I have a database with drivers and a combobox which is populated with the drivers. But when I add a new driver with a button Add Driver, it's added only in Microsoft Access table, not in the combobox. And once I reload the program, the new driver is deleted from the database. I also have connected the database in Data Source and I can edit the tables only from there(if I want to edit the combobox).

This is my connection with the database

```cs
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    con = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.Oledb.12.0;Data Source=transportDateBase.accdb");
    cmd = new OleDbCommand();
    con.Open();
    cmd.Connection = con;
    string query = "SELECT Name FROM Drivers";
    cmd.CommandText = query;
    OleDbDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        comboDriver.Items.Add(reader["Name"]);
    }
    con.Close();
```

and this is my Add Driver button:

```cs
OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection();
conn.ConnectionString = ("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.Oledb.12.0;Data Source=transportDateBase.accdb");

String Id = textID.Text;
String Name = textName.Text;
String Age = textAge.Text;
String City = textCity.Text;

OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("INSERT into Drivers (Id, Name, Age, City) Values(@Id, @Name, @Age, @City)");
cmd.Connection = conn;

conn.Open();

if (conn.State == ConnectionState.Open)
{
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Id", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = Id;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Name", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = Name;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Age", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = Age;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@City", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = City;

    try
    {
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        MessageBox.Show("New Driver Added");
        conn.Close();
    }
    catch (OleDbException ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Source);
        conn.Close();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Just because you've added it to your database, doesn't mean anything else will happen.

You still need to update your UI.

Add this in after you have executed the query:

```
comboDriver.Items.Add(Name);
```

As an aside, you should also wrap the conn.Open() in a try catch as well